# what preposition to use with the "senden"?

Tags: preposition

How do I know what preposition I should use with the verb "senden".  I have a sentence of "Senden Sie Ihre Bewerbungsunterlagen ..." but don't know which preposition to use.

Comment: If you would like to send the documents to someone, it should be "Senden Sie Ihre Unterlagen an jemanden" (an requires Akkusativ - an wen oder was senden Sie Ihre Unterlagen?")

Comment: Usually, it's **an**, but **nach** is used with named locations, e.g. *Senden Sie Ihre Bewerbungsunterlagen nach Berlin.*

Comment: @Janka: Please take some time and write answers instead of just commenting. Even short answers are welcome (from my view they are much better than lengthy essays on borderline topics). [Comments are not a replacement for answers and may be removed any time without further notice](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/431/why-should-i-edit-or-answer-rather-than-comment?).

Answer (score 6):

**For the special case of *Bewerbungsunterlagen***

Most usual use-cases are:

> Senden Sie Ihre Bewerbungsunterlagen **an Herrn Müller**!.
>
> Senden Sie Ihre Bewerbungsunterlagen **an die Personalstelle** der Firma XYZ!

**Generally**

The preposition is not so much depending on the verb, rather on the destination (and to some extent the purpose). In combination with the verb *senden* you may have all sorts of prepositions:

> Senden Sie dieses Paket **nach München**!
>
> Senden Sie dieses Paket **an Herrn Macron**!
>
> Senden Sie dieses Paket **zur Bundesverwaltungsstelle für Bevollmächtigungsbedarfserhebung** in Braunschweig!
>
> Senden Sie dieses Paket **auf die Malediven**!
>
> Senden Sie diese Pakete **in die Länder der Balkanregion**!
>
> Senden Sie dieses Pakt **nach Frankreich**!
>
> Senden Sie dieses Paket **in die Türkei**!
>
> Senden Sie dieses Paket **in den Hafen**!
>
> Senden Sie dieses Paket **an die Zwergelberg-Grundschule**!
>
> Senden Sie dieses Paket **auf den Mars**!
>
> Senden Sie dieses Paket **in die Andromedagalaxie**!
>
> Senden Sie dieses Paket **zu mir nachhause**!
>
> Senden Sie dieses Pakt **um die Welt**!
>
> Senden Sie diese Presseerklärung **in die Welt hinaus**!
>
> Senden Sie diesen Brief **zur Gräfin Hohenstein**!
>
> Senden Sie diesen Brief **an die Gräfin Hohenstein**!
>
> Senden Sie diesen Brief **der Gräfin Hohenstein**!
>
> Senden Sie diesen Brief **Herrn Professor** Schlauberger!
>
> Senden Sie diesen Brief **dem Herrn Macron**!
>
> Senden Sie diesen Brief einmal quer **durch die EU**!
>
> Senden Sie diesen Brief **unter allen Umständen**!

<sup>(The last one is a joke.)</sup>

So you have to learn the prepositions that are in use with the specific locations or types of locations (cities, countries, institutions, etc.), and also be aware of different purposes. I am afraid it needs a lot of practice to get this right.

Comment: Vor allem: Senden Sie die Bewerbungsunterlagen ab! :) Und natürlich fort. In die Ablage Rund. Nicht. Sofort.

Answer (score 2):

You can always use a dative:

> "Senden Sie Herrn Müller Ihre Bewerbungsunterlagen."

Comment: Bis auf die Wortstellung im Satz äquivalent zu "Senden Sie diesen Brief Herrn Professor Schlauberger!" von Christian Geiselmann. Was ist an Deiner Antwort besser?

Answer (score 1):

If you send something to a person you would say "an" or "zu". eg: "Ich sende es an/zu Frau Meier", "Ich sende es an/zu jemanden aus der Personalabteilung", etc.. i think "an" is more common than "zu" but both is ok.

If you send something to a place you would say "nach" or "zu". eg: "Ich sende es nach Berlin", "Ich sende es nach Hause", "Ich sende es zu dem Postfach" etc.. " "nach" and "zu" are not always replaceable by each other. it is a little bit difficult to recognize which of them is correct in a certain case for native german speaker too.